# Difference between if(rdy) and if(rdy == 1)?

Tags: syntax, verilog, hdl

Is there a difference between the two?

I have just changed from `if(rdy)` to `if(rdy == 1)` in some code for a project, and suddenly the output behaves totally different.

Assumes `rdy` is a 1-bit `reg` datatype in Verilog.

Comment: That may very well be the case, I will investigate this a bit further. However, this may blow this question out of proportion, but when synthesized and downloaded to a target device, `reg` can only be 1 or 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
reg rdy;

if (rdy)     <--->   if (rdy!=1'b0)
if (rdy==1)  <--->   if (rdy==1'b1)
```

For synthesis, they will probably work the same. But be aware if `rdy` has more than 1 bit:

```
reg[7:0] rdy;

if (rdy)     <--->   if (rdy!=8'b00000000)
if (rdy==1)  <--->   if (rdy==8'b00000001)
```

The first one will probably be synthetized using an 8-input `OR` gate, while the second one will need a 7-input `NOR` gate and a 2-input `AND` gate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two.

`reg` is 4-state: 0, 1, x, z.  Only if `rdy` is 1 will the `if` condition be true; otherwise, it is false.

```
module tb;

reg rdy;

always @(rdy) begin
    if (rdy) begin
        $display($time, " rdy=%b if (rdy)    TRUE", rdy);
    end else begin
        $display($time, " rdy=%b if (rdy)    FALSE", rdy);
    end

    if (rdy==1) begin
        $display($time, " rdy=%b if (rdy==1) TRUE", rdy);
    end else begin
        $display($time, " rdy=%b if (rdy==1) FALSE", rdy);
    end
    $display;
end

initial begin
    #5 rdy = 1'b1;
    #5 rdy = 1'bx;
    #5 rdy = 1'bz;
    #5 rdy = 1'b0;
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
           5 rdy=1 if (rdy)    TRUE
           5 rdy=1 if (rdy==1) TRUE

          10 rdy=x if (rdy)    FALSE
          10 rdy=x if (rdy==1) FALSE

          15 rdy=z if (rdy)    FALSE
          15 rdy=z if (rdy==1) FALSE

          20 rdy=0 if (rdy)    FALSE
          20 rdy=0 if (rdy==1) FALSE
```